# select particular td in a tr in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this

```
<table class="MainTable">
    <tr>
        <td>xxxx</td>
        <td>yyy</td>
        <tr>
            <th>AAAAA</th>
            <td>yyy</td>
            <td>ZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to select second td in tr .
When i used css styling 
                .MainTable tr td:nth-child(2)

It works fine for the first tr, but for second tr , it selects the second td.
i want to select the third td in second tr with a common formula.

Comment: You have a wrong formatted table in your example.

Comment: Your table structure in wrong.

Answer (score 3):

So just select the third `td` in the second `tr` like that:

```css
.MainTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:red;
}
```

And you miss a  in your html:

```
<table class="MainTable">
    <tr>
        <td>xxxx</td>
        <td>yyy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>AAAAA</th>
        <td>yyy</td>
        <td>ZZZZ</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you have serious problems with your table structure. A table has to contain one or more `<tbody>` children and a `<tr>` can't contain other `<tr>`s (unless contained in an inner table).

If I get you correctly, you want to select the second td in every row, i.e you want to disregard the `<th>` in the second row when calculating which is the "second td". This can be achieved using [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead of `:nth-child()`, as the former only considers elements of the same type when calculating their indices.

Note though that both `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` are only supported in IE9 and above.